# integrate libgdx live wallpaper with appflood

Tags: android, libgdx, interstitial

i have integrate everything properly.
the only problem is when i want to load the ads(any ads of appflood)
the example is interstitial ads

```
AppFlood.showFullScreen(this);
```

the error is

```
The method showFullScreen(Activity) in the type AppFlood is not applicable for the arguments (LiveWallpaper)
```

i ever integrate appflood with my libgdx game that extend AndroidApplication  class, but in live wallpaper this doesn't work. i want to make appflood works in libgdx livewallpaper too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This a reply to @newbieUser comment

```
AppFlood.initialize(this, "", "", AppFlood.AD_ALL);
AppFlood.setEventDelegate( new AFEventDelegate() {  
@Override
public void onClose(JSONObject arg0) {
finish();
}

@Override
public void onClick(JSONObject arg0) {

}
});


AppFlood.showFullScreen(this);
```

AppFlood.setEventDelegate is used to add listener

Comment: hey, thank this work.
and for others that have the same problem, don't forget to add this line when calling your activity
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
and call finish(); onClick method too

Answer (score 4):

create a activity class which shows appflood in its onCreate() method

and attach a listner to app flood to give you a callback that app flood is closed or not.

on its close call back finish your activity.

call the intent for this activity in your onCreateEngine() method

This should help you out

Comment: this way u can integrate other adds also

Comment: hi, i have create an activity which appflood in oncreate method. and call the intent in oncreateengine Intent intent = new Intent(this, AndroidStarter.class);
  startActivity(intent);
but i don't know what you mean by attach a listener to appflood, how could i do this? and then check is appflood is close or not?